# Excel Table and Pivot Table Data changes with one Slicer

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have Excel table (Ctr + T) and made a pivot table using the same excel table on the different excel tab.
is there any way that i can change both (Excel Table and pivot table) with one slicer.or probably change in one slicer result in change in other slicer.

i have seen video and other question and answer forum,they are not serving the purpose.

I tried to connect the both slicer by going into **report connection** option in slicer. but im unable to find the second slicer name.

Answer (score 0):

If you create two slicers, one for the table and one for the pivot table, you can control the table slicer from an event macro. Put this in your *ThisWorkbook* module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    Dim PivotSlicer As SlicerCache
    Dim TableSlicer As SlicerCache

    Set PivotSlicer = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("<Name of pivot slicer>")
    Set TableSlicer = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("<Name of table slicer>")

    Dim PivotSlicerItem As SlicerItem
    Dim TableSlicerItem As SlicerItem

    TableSlicer.ClearAllFilters
    For Each PivotSlicerItem In PivotSlicer.SlicerItems
        Set TableSlicerItem = TableSlicer.SlicerItems(PivotSlicerItem.Name)
        TableSlicerItem.Selected = PivotSlicerItem.Selected
    Next
End Sub
```

Update the names of the slicers in lines 5 and 6. This will go through the items in the pivot slicer and set the table slicer to the same values.

The table slicer is needed, but should be made invisible.

Comment: Hi @Sam .. I kep the above code in "this Workbook" under project explorer. also change the slicer names in the line number  5 and 6.. but its still not working. :(

Comment: Put a breakpoint in line 11 and inspect the values of PivotSlicer and TableSlicer when the code stops. Are they empty?

Comment: Hi Sam , I tried putting breakpoint in line 11 and ran again but nothing seems working.
i placed a "VBA_Example" Named file at below path.

https://github.com/supersaiyan12/Query

Comment: Sorry. I will not download an .xlsm file.
I'm fairly sure the code above works. My suggestion is that you create a new clean workbook with minimal amount of code and data and see if you can make it work.

Comment: This does not seem to work even on an empty workbook with dummy info, is there anything missing? Do we have to enable a feature?